# React update state on filter index

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an app where I have listed a bunch of retailers for a car company. I use a state to determin which company is selected in the list, and they use the selected company to generate excellists and so forth, and up until recently I had all the retailers in one list and an onChange that set the state, however, the retailers have gotten so many that I implemented a searchfunction so that they dont have to scroll through 50+ retailers, but now I cant set state since, if they search for their own ID they will pop up in the selectbox, however I cant set state like this, is there any way to automatically set state to index 0 when I search?

Code here:

```
const FilterList = ({ ...props }) => {
return (
<div className="filter-list">
  <div className="row">
    <p className="headline text-left">Välj återförsäljare först</p>
  </div>
  <div className="row">
    <div className="group">
      <input
        required
        className="input-text"
        type="text"
        onChange={(ev) => props.updateFilter(ev)}
      />
      <span className="highlight"></span>
      <span className="bar"></span>
      <label>Sök återförsäljare via id</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <AfSelect af={props.af} filterBy={props.filterBy} selectedAf={props.selectedAf} />
</div>
)
}
```

And here is the selectboxlist, which worked up until I implemented the searchfunction:

```
const AfSelect = ({ ...props }) => {
return (
<div>
  <select className="select-input" onChange={(ev) => props.selectedAf(ev)}>
    {
      props.af.filter(item => item.afid.indexOf(props.filterBy) > -1)
        .map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <option
              key={index}
              value={item.afid}
            >
              {item.name} {item.afid}
            </option>
          )
        })
    }
  </select>
  <p></p>
</div>
)
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the problem that when searching the index of a selected item is incorrect? Also, please show the `selectedAf()` function.

Comment: Hi, the problem is that the user "thinks" that they selected the retailer since it shows up in the list, but they need to actually click it to set the state.. So I would like to implement an auto setting of the state when I use filter to the item with index 0.

`selectedAf = (ev) => {
    this.setState({ selectedAf: ev.target.value });
  }`

Comment: to be clear; when the user has typed something in the searchbar, it should automatically select the first item in the list?

Comment: Yes, thats the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just modify the `updateFilter()` function. Since you want this to apply whenever the user enter a filter, it makes sense to do this when the input value is changed:

```
updateFilter = (ev) => {
  let obj = Object.assign({}, this.state);
  if(ev.target.value.length > 0) {
    let name = af.filter(item => item.afid.indexOf(ev.target.value) > -1)[0];
    obj.selectedAf = name;
  }
  obj.filterBy = ev.target.value;
  this.setState(obj);
}
```

The above is just a rough example of how you could implement this. The scope of certain variables, such as `af`, etc is unknown based on the limited code you provided. But the *logic* should work.

But basically, if the input has something entered, do a `filter` on `af` and get the result at index `0`. This will be our `selectedAf`. Then, save the state with the search term and the selected item.

Comment: Thank you @Chris! I ended up doing this:

`updateFilter = (ev) => {
    this.setState({ filterBy: ev.target.value });
    let name = this.state.af.filter(item => item.afid.indexOf(ev.target.value) > -1) [0];
    this.setState({ selectedAf: name.afid })
  }`